# Yandex API geocode

Tags: java, encoding, yandex

I am trying to receive coordinates for address using Yandex geocode. To get started I created a query directly like it is described here https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geocoder/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/

However, it responds that uri is not correct. As I found out, it is because uri contains Russian letters. I tried to fix it using URLEncoder, but nothing changed. Will be grateful for any kind of help.

```
import com.sun.deploy.net.URLEncoder;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String address = "Санкт-Петербург";
        try {
            URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("BAD");
        }
        System.out.println(address);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        String request = "https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=" + address;
        GetMethod method = new GetMethod(request);
        String Lat="",Long="";
        try {
            client.executeMethod(method);
            String s = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
            System.out.print(s);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri '[https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=Санкт-Петербург](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?geocode=%D0%A1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3)': Invalid query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually encode the string.

Please try

```
address = URLEncoder.encode(...
```

Comment: ohhh :) Thank you, it helped